# ¿Cómo sumar un valor por nombre encontrado usando python en un Excel?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Quiero crear una automatización para que cuando busque por input un nombre en una lista de excel, le sume al valor correspondiente de la celda siguiente + 1 al número que ya posee.

La lista de excel es la siguiente:

('NOMBRES', 'ASISTENCIAS')
('ACTONI', 14)
('ALKA', 23)

La idea es que cuando en el input ponga por ejemplo ACTONI, le sume 1 a ese 14.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

FILE_PATH = 'Prueba.xlsx'
SHEET = 'Prueba'

workbook = load_workbook(FILE_PATH)
sheet = workbook[SHEET]
wb = workbook
busqueda = input('Ingresa el nombre: ')

for row in sheet.values:
    if busqueda in row:
        print(f'Sumar una asistencia a {busqueda}')  # desde aqui ya no se como seleccionar la siguiente celda y darle el valor.

wb.save('Prueba.xlsx')
```

No sé si iré bien pero eso es lo poco que pude entender y aprender hasta ahora. No sé cómo colocar para que detecte la celda siguiente al nombre y le sume el += 1 a la asistencia. También probé con pandas pero se me complicó más la sintaxis.

Comment: Desconozco openpyxl, pero ya que te te permite hacer algo como `busqueda in row` posiblemente implemente también `row.index(busqueda)` que te devolverá un entero que es el número de columna donde se encontró (contando desde 0). Sumando 1 a eso tendrías el índice donde está el dato a cambiar y seguramente podrías hacer `row[indice] += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas, siguiendo la línea de tu código:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
FILE_PATH = 'Prueba.xlsx'
SHEET = 'Prueba'

workbook = load_workbook(FILE_PATH)
sheet = workbook[SHEET]
wb = workbook.active
```

Agregué esta línea, la verdad no sé si es estrictamente necesaria, pero siempre la uso.

```
busqueda = input('Ingresa el nombre: ')
```

hasta acá todo igual

```
for fila,col in sheet:
```

Agrego una variable para la columna y omito leer el valor para obtener la posición

```
if busqueda in fila.value:
```

Ahora si uso value, es necesario para saber que contiene

```
    wb[f'B{col.row}']=col.value + 1
    print("Asistencia agregada")
```

bueno declaro que celda modificaré y a su valor le sumo 1

```
workbook.save('Prueba.xlsx')
```

Grabamos

Eso basicamente.